# The IP address configured for the host-only network is not within the allowed ranges

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I got this error when I run `vagrant up` on my macOS:

> The IP address configured for the host-only network is not within the
> allowed ranges. Please update the address used to be within the
> allowed ranges and run the command again.
>
> Address: 192.168.10.10   Ranges: 192.168.56.0/21

The same `Vagrantfile` works before, but not any more.

Any idea?

Comment: Was this issue with Laravel homestead?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I found the "issue" started to happen after VirtualBox 6.1.26.

The way to solve is creating a new file at `/etc/vbox/networks.conf` on your macOS with content

```
* 10.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16
* 2001::/64
```

Make sure including the **asterisks** `*`. Then the issue should be gone.

Regarding the `networks.conf` content, it can be found at https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly

Comment: Vagrant was still throwing issues for me when adding this, a quick restart sorted that.

Comment: Thanks!. Have to mention that the character * is a must, firstly I though it was for enumerating a list of values. Full doc: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly

Comment: Confirming this fix for Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Comment: I don't have the permissions to create the directory `/etc/vbox/`, which I don't have. Of course, I could use `sudo` to create this directory, but are you sure this is the right solution? Why can't you just configure the IP address in the Vagrantfile, as explained in the other answer?

Comment: This works for me with ubuntu 22.04. Kudos

Comment: works for Linux Mint!

Answer (score 11):

By modifying the vagrantfile as below, it works for me.

```
cfg.vm.network "private_network", ip:"192.168.56.10"
```

I just changed the ip address from "192.168.1.10" to "192.168.56.10".

(Thanks to link in @Hongbo Miao's answers. (https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly))

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem on MacOs with my Laravel Homestead and I solved doing:

```
sudo su -
mkdir /etc/vbox/
cd /etc/vbox/
echo '* 0.0.0.0/0 ::/0' > /etc/vbox/networks.conf
chmod 644 /etc/vbox/networks.conf
```

Answer (score 4):

Changing a Vagrantfile directly is not recommended if you didn't create it.
You can use this instead

```
vagrant config static_ip 192.168.56.2
```

The ip address can be any in the range 192.168.56.2 - 192.168.63.254. Make sure to run `vagrant reload` after making changes.

Comment: yes, a /21 network can be calculated [here](https://www.calculator.net/ip-subnet-calculator.html?cclass=any&csubnet=21&cip=192.168.56.0&ctype=ipv4&printit=0&x=97&y=9)

Answer (score 3):

Easy Solve

```
$ mkdir /etc/vbox/
$cd /etc/vbox/
```

vbox$ sudo vi networks.conf

```
  * 10.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16
  * 2001::/64
```

Answer (score 2):

These are some trouble shooting steps that i took for resolving the issue.

1. In the System Preferences under Security & Privacy, enabling VirtualBox / Oracle.
2. After the changes restart the VirtualBox

If these doesn't resolve the issue check the following in you Vagrant File.

> Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
> os = "generic/ubuntu2004"
> net_ip = "192.168.**50**"

As you can see the ip range given is not what vagrant is looking for. Change the net_ip value to 192.168.**56** .

This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on macOS after a system upgrade.
In the `System Preferences` under `Security & Privacy`, enabling `VirtualBox / Oracle` solved it.

Comment: I don't see "VirtualBox / Oracle" anywhere when I go to "Security & Privacy" and, of course, I am using VirtualBox as the provider.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue solved by the following steps

sudo nano  /etc/vbox/networks.conf

- 10.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16
- 2001::/64
- 0.0.0.0/0 ::/0

sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart

Comment: I was using addresses like `172.16.3.X` and because of the `* 0.0.0.0/0` in this answer, it basically fixed it so all my old VM IP addresses worked again!  Looks like the formatting didn't preserve the `*` symbols correctly though

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your Virtualbox is updated! A reinstall solved this problem.